# C# ?? operator and ora-12704: character set mismatch

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have asp.net mvc 4 application with EF 4, .net 4
This code

```
public List<ListItem> GetViolatedArticlesByLaw(int lawId, string culture)
{
        culture = culture.ToLower();

        var ans = 
            (from art in context.TITLENORMALAWs.Where(l => l.PARENTID == lawId)
            select new ListItem
            {
                ID = art.ID,
                ParentID = lawId,
                Value = (art.NUM_STATSTR ?? ""),
            });
        Debug.WriteLine( ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)ans).ToTraceString() );

        return ans.ToList();
}
```

throws ora-12704: character set mismatch.
It runs perfectly fine if I select from List, like this: `from art in context.TITLENORMALAWs.Where(l => l.PARENTID == lawId).ToList()`

This is the SQL generated:

```
SELECT 
"Extent1"."ID" AS "ID", 
:p__linq__1 AS "C1", 
CASE WHEN ("Extent1"."NUM_STATSTR" IS NULL) THEN '' ELSE "Extent1"."NUM_STATSTR" END AS "C2"
FROM "AISSMK"."TITLENORMALAW" "Extent1"
WHERE ("Extent1"."PARENTID" = :p__linq__0)
```

It produces the same error in sqldeveloper and if I change this piece `THEN '' ELSE` to this `THEN n'' ELSE` it runs ok.
NUM_STATSTR in table definition is NVARCHAR2(30)

How can I make linq generate proper sql? Or do I have to call `ToList()` before selecting and there is no other way?

Comment: Have you tried using the LINQ equivalent of select? I'm seeing you used the `ToList()` extension method so you probably have `System.Linq` referenced.

Comment: Yes, the same result

Comment: This case in query doesn't make sense, because empty string is stored as null in oracle. I don't know if framework will replace it, but probably not. In general try to always save string in variable, then it is translated into parameter - this might change something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Orif I think you should try to build the query manually instead of using the LINQ-to-SQL generators.

Try using the `ExecuteQuery`method on the `DataContext` class and try to add a cast to `NVARCHAR`

For more help read here, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20d456f0-9174-4745-bbc5-571f68879e27/net-strings-sql-paramater-type-always-nvarchar?forum=linqtosql

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was that empty strings are treated as null by Oracle, so your code `Value = (art.NUM_STATSTR ?? "")` actually ends up looking like `Value = (art.NUM_STATSTR ?? null)`. Our workaround looks like this:

```
    var ans = 
        (from art in context.TITLENORMALAWs
         where art.PARENTID == lawId
         select new
         {
            ID = art.ID,
            ParentID = lawId,
            Value = (art.NUM_STATSTR ?? ""),
         })
         .ToList()
         .Select(a => new ListItem{
             ID = a.ID,
             ParentID = a.ParentID,
             Value = a.Value ?? "",
         });
```