# NHibernate casting string parameters in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, linq, nhibernate, parameters

Using NHibernate and Oracle, I'm running into an issue when ordering on a conditional.
Say I've got these entities (and their corresponding database types):

```
public class Contact
{
    public virtual int PrimaryKey { get; set; } // number(38,0) NOT NULL
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }    // nvarchar2(max) NULL
    public virtual int? CompanyFk { get; set; } // number(38,0) NULL
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
public class Company
{
    public virtual int PrimaryKey { get; set; } // number(38,0) NOT NULL
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }    // nvarchar2(max) NULL
}
```

Mapped in a conventional way such that using Linq, I can query like this:

```
var boeingEmployees = Context.Contacts.Where(c => c.Company.Name == "Boeing");
```

The trouble begins if I do something like this:

```
var query = Context.Contacts.OrderBy(c => c.Company == null ? null : c.Company.Name);
```

In this context, maybe the above is silly, but I have multiple cases where I may have a conditional OrderBy. So what NHibernate translates this to is something like this:

```
SELECT CONTACT.PRIMARYKEY, CONTACT.NAME, CONTACT.COMPANYFK
FROM CONTACT
LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANY ON CONTACT.COMPANYFK = COMPANY.PRIMARYKEY
ORDER BY CAST(CASE WHEN CONTACT.COMPANYFK IS NULL THEN :p0 ELSE COMPANY.NAME END AS NVARCHAR(255)) ASC;
```

with the parameter p0 being null. Or I can make it string.Empty, or "abc". No matter the string, the parameter itself is of type varchar2, whereas COMPANY.NAME is nvarchar2. This Oracle exception gets thrown:

ORA-12704: character set mismatch

If I fiddle with the SQL so that the orderby looks like this,

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CONTACT.COMPANYFK IS NULL THEN CAST(:p0 AS NVARCHAR2(255)) ELSE COMPANY.NAME END ASC
```

then the query works fine. But obviously, this is NHibernate generated code that I can't (I think) really alter it in practice.

So the question for those few working with NHibernate and Oracle... What's the best way to handle this? Is there a way to cast the parameter? Or set a default string char set within NHibernate?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# ?? operator and ora-12704: character set mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082826/c-sharp-operator-and-ora-12704-character-set-mismatch)

Comment: @shA.t yea, it looks like it's the same kind of problem, in the Select vs OrderBy. The data types in the different case statements don't match.

Answer (score 0):

Use AnsiString in your mapping for that particular property. Then you will not have these castings.

Comment: Seems a bit backwards to have to change the database to accommodate this weird quirk. Plus for legacy purposes I need to keep the database untouched.

Comment: I never said you should change the database. Just change the mapping.